# InvalidByteSequenceError deploying Volt via Intercity

Tags: css, deployment, capistrano, assets, voltrb

I don't know how to tell if this is an issue with Volt or [Intercity](https://intercityup.com/), but while I have successfully deployed other rack apps via Intercity/`Capistrano`, when I deploy a Volt app, I get errors compiling CSS files when I visit the page.

`Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError "\xE2" on US-ASCII`

Happens consistently for `.css.scss` files, and I've gotten it to stop happening on my own files by converting them all to `.scss`, but occasionally it happens on other files as well (in particular, at least one in `volt-foundation` and in `volt-font_awesome`).

Any idea why?

Comment: what version of ruby is on the server?

Comment: Both the server and my Gemfile are set at 2.2.2

Comment: Hmmmm...but the error itself shows the line of the error in execjs under bundle/ruby/2.2.0/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the encoding. To fix, put these lines at the top of your Gemfile.

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

See the article [here](http://www.a.rnaud.net/2011/10/how-to-fix-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-in-bundler-installation/) for a discussion.